# Need a query to select specific comments with the name of the writer

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I have a database contains 3 tables, as following:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE posts 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id) 
);

CREATE TABLE comments
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    post_id INTEGER REFERENCES posts(id),
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id)
    -- parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES comments(id)
);
```

I need a query to select all the comments for one specific post using the id of this post. What made me struggling is how to select the name of the user who wrote the comment!

This is what I tried :

```
select  
    c.body as cbody, p.body as pbody, c.user_id as user_id 
from 
    users u 
inner join 
    posts p on u.id = p.user_id 
inner join 
    comments c on c.post_id = p.id 
where 
    p.id=($1)
```

Any help??

Comment: What is wrong with your current query?

Comment: I cannot return the correct name of the user who wrote the comment! @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I cannot return the correct name of the user who wrote the comment! @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Comments table as the first table in the FROM clause, since that's your main table for your query data. (Just personal preference, not a requirement.)

After that, I would join the Users table on Comments.user_id to get the comments' authors.

You probably do not want the post's body included with every comment, so I would leave that out.

So my query would look something like this:

```
SELECT c.body AS cbody, c.user_id AS user_id, u.name AS uname
FROM Comments c LEFT JOIN Users u ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE c.post_id=($1);
```

An INNER JOIN might be valid too, but you need to be sure that Comments.user_id is always filled. When Comments.user_id is NULL, the comment will not be included in the queries result when INNER JOIN is used.

Comment: This is cool, but I need to display all comments for specific post id.
So i need the condition "where" to be added!  Where and how can I do this? @Bart

Comment: Just added it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I removed the original post's body from the query, since IMHO your query should only fetch comment data of a specific post. If you need specific details about the post, like the post body and the post author, I would execute a separate SELECT query for that. It is impossible to fetch all post and comment data efficiently within a single query (without duplicating a lot of data in your result).